# Remove inner portion of object

Tags: inkscape

I'm rather new to Inkscape (always worked with photoshop/gimp) so please excuse my ignorance here.

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I have an object that needs to have a certain part in the center of it removed. Like for example the inside circle in this image.
[image]

(Excuse the leopard print.) I know how to create objects in Inkscape but how would I "delete" a certain inner part of it?

This is probably the wrong way to say this but I can't think of any other way to explain it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform multiple operations with vector objects. From your picture I am afraid you try to perform operations on raster and vector objects, this is why path functions will not produce desirable results. You can use MASK functions instead of path functions.

Create two vector objects and play with this menu -

[image]